# Google API not returning refresh token once already requested one

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api

I've recently been working quite a lot with the google API. I had some trouble getting the refresh token. So i googled a bit and found the "`setAccessType('offline')`" and "`setApprovalPrompt('force')`". It did return a refresh token, so i was quite excited. But after 2 hours, i checked what it had been doing and i saw i had no refresh token, apparently when i fetch an access token with my refresh token, it returns an access token, and expiry stuff, but it doesn't return an

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
} else if (isset($_POST['authcode'])) {
    $authCode = $_POST['authcode'];

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
} else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    /* ... Code to handle the Auth Code */
}
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

Any further questions? Be free to ask

Comment: What is the issues with offline access token. because I have already application in which i am also using offline access so may i help you.

Comment: @DineshBhojvani There isn't really a problem with the offline access token, the problem is that when i request a new token with my refresh token, it doesn't give me another refresh token to use in a later request. Which ends up that my code isn't able to communicate with the google api